# What is a word for "available time"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I writing a sentence as follow:

> The time made available and financial resources imposed their limits on the scope of this research.

I feel that "the time made available" is a bit odd. Is there a word for "available time" or "time made available"?

Comment: You are right. "Time made available..." seems as if the writer is complaining against the person responsible for allocating the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative could be:

> Limited time and financial resources reduced/constrained the scope of this research.

Answer (score 5):

I would write: "Time and financial constraints limited the scope of this research."